# Caret returns different predictions with caret train object than it does with the extracted final model

Tags: r, prediction, r-caret

I prefer to use caret when fitting models because of its relative speed and preprocessing capabilities. However, I'm slightly confused on how it makes predictions. When comparing predictions made directly from the train object and predictions made from the extracted final model, I'm seeing very different numbers. The predictions from the train object appear to be more accurate.

```
library(caret)
library(ranger)

x1 <- rnorm(100)
x2 <- rbeta(100, 1, 1)

y <- 2*x1 + x2 + 5*x1*x2

data <- data.frame(x1, x2, y)
fitRanger <- train(y ~ x1 + x2, data = data,
                   method = 'ranger', 
                   tuneLength = 1,
                   preProcess = c('knnImpute', 'center', 'scale'))

predict.data <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(10), x2 = rbeta(10, 1, 1))
prediction1 <- predict(fitRanger, newdata = predict.data)
prediction2 <- predict(fitRanger$finalModel, data = predict.data)$prediction

results <- data.frame(prediction1, prediction2)
results
```

I'm positive it has something to do with how I preprocess the data in the train object, but even when I preprocess the test data and use the Ranger model to make predictions, the values are different

```
predict.data.processed <- predict.data %>% 
                             preProcess(method = c('knnImpute', 
                                                   'center', 
                                                   'scale')) %>% .$data

results3 <- predict(fitRanger$finalModel, data = predict.data.processed)$prediction

results <- cbind(results, results3)
results
```

I want to extract the predictions from each individual tree in the ranger model, which I can't do in caret. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the same predictions from the final model as with caret `train` you should pre-process the data in the same way. Using your example with `set.seed(1)`:

caret predict:

```
prediction1 <- predict(fitRanger,
                       newdata = predict.data)
```

ranger predict on the final model. caret pre process was used on predict.data

```
prediction2 <- predict(fitRanger$finalModel,
                       data = predict(fitRanger$preProcess,
                                      predict.data))$prediction

all.equal(prediction1,
          prediction2)
#output
TRUE
```