# Extracting predictions from caret's train function

Tags: r, r-caret, glmnet

I am trying to reproduce *missuse*’s working [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50397115/caret-returns-different-predictions-with-caret-train-object-than-it-does-with-th) for pulling out predictions from caret’s train function. I am using eleastic net and just cannot get it.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
require(caret)   
require(glmnet)

x = matrix(rnorm(100 * 20), 100, 20)   
set.seed(3) 
g = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = TRUE)

df = as.data.frame(x) 
g_f = as.factor(g) 
df$g_f = g_f

train_control <- trainControl(   
method="cv",    
number = 3,    
savePredictions = T)

sorozat = seq(0, 1, 0.25)

search_grid <- expand.grid(   
alpha = sorozat,    
lambda = sorozat )

set.seed(3) 
fit2 <- train(g_f ~ .,    
data = df,    
trControl = train_control,    
tuneGrid = search_grid,   
preProc = c("BoxCox", "center", "scale"),   
method = "glmnet")
```

And my attempt, which gives an error:

```
prediction2 <- predict(fit2$finalModel,
                       data = predict(fit2$preProcess,
                                      df))$prediction
```

> Error in predict.glmnet(fit2$finalModel, data = predict(fit2, df)) :
> You need to supply a value for 'newx'

Below is how I can get a prediction. But how can I be sure if it's the right one if its confusion matrix:

```
# CM ver.1
pred_f = predict(fit2, df)
cm = as.data.frame(pred_f)
cm$g = g_f
table(cm)
      g
pred_f  0  1
     0 29  9
     1 15 47
```

is different from the one provided by the model?

```
# CM ver.2
confusionMatrix(fit2)$table
          Reference
Prediction  0  1
         0 23 16
         1 21 40
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit: Added the output of confusion matrices.

Comment: Thanks for the notice! I corrected it, but the error still remains

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linked answer does not work for glmnet since [`predict.glmnet`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glmnet/versions/1.1-1/topics/predict.glmnet) has some peculiarities:

the data argument to `predict.glmnet` is called `newx` and must be a matrix.

Apart from that this predict function uses all fitted lambda to create predictions, so if you want the best one you must specify so. Additionally it is advisable to set the response to your linking:

using your example the optimal fit values were alpha = 0.5 and lambda = 0.25. The alpha is set inside the model but the lambda must be specified during prediction.

But first we must preprocess the test data (same as in the linked answer):

```
predict(fit2$preProcess, df)
```

this however returns a data frame with the class column, so in order to supply it to `predict.glmnet` the response column (factor) must be removed and the data frame converted to a matrix:

```
as.matrix(predict(fit2$preProcess, df)[,-21])
```

Now to call `predict.glmnet` with the optimal lambda of 0.25 setting the prediction type to class:

```
library(glmnet)
prediction2 <- predict(fit2$finalModel,
                       newx = as.matrix(predict(fit2$preProcess,
                                      df)[,-21]),
                       type = "class",
                       s = 0.25)

head(prediction2)
     1  
[1,] "0"
[2,] "1"
[3,] "0"
[4,] "0"
[5,] "0"
[6,] "0"
```

**EDIT:** to answer the edited question about confusion matrix differences.

When you call `confusionMatrix` on the output of `train` then the resulting matrix is obtained from the out of fold predictions during resampling - is less biased since these are test set predictions.

When you fit a model on all of the data (this is `fit2$finalModel`) and use it to predict on the same data you are creating train set predictions - has a lot of bias since the model was fit using these observations. This is the reason the off diagonal sum is much less in this case compared to calling `confusionMatrix` on `fit2`. This is sometimes referred to overfitting - the model predicts much better the data it has already seen.

In short

```
`confusionMatrix(fit2)`
```

produces a confusion matrix from the out of fold predictions. This can be used as a metric for model selection.

while

```
confusionMatrix(as.factor(prediction2), g_f)
```

produces a highly biased confusion matrix based on the model prediction on the train data. This should not be used as a metric for model selection.

**EDTI2:** It just occurred to me that this might be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

If you just want the cross validated prediction you can simply use:

```
fit2$pred
```

If you want to calculate the AUC for these you should specify you want class probabilities in trainControl:

```
train_control <- trainControl(   
  method="cv",    
  number = 3,    
  savePredictions = TRUE,
  classProbs = TRUE)
```

one additional concern is that class levels need to be valid variables names, so numbers such as 0 and 1 wont work, an easy fix is:

```
df$g_f <- factor(df$g_f,
                 levels = c(0, 1),
                 labels = c("zero", "one"))
```

After the fit:

```
set.seed(3) 
fit2 <- train(g_f ~ .,    
              data = df,    
              trControl = train_control,    
              tuneGrid = search_grid,   
              preProc = c("BoxCox", "center", "scale"),   
              method = "glmnet")
```

the predictions are in `fit2$pred`:

```
head(fit2$pred)
#output
  pred  obs rowIndex      zero       one alpha lambda Resample
1  one  one        2 0.4513397 0.5486603     0      1    Fold1
2 zero zero        4 0.5764889 0.4235111     0      1    Fold1
3 zero  one        5 0.5154925 0.4845075     0      1    Fold1
4  one  one        6 0.4836418 0.5163582     0      1    Fold1
5 zero zero        7 0.5199623 0.4800377     0      1    Fold1
6  one zero        8 0.4770536 0.5229464     0      1    Fold1
```

These predictions are for all tested hyper parameter combinations to get just for the best performing hyper pars:

```
library(tidyverse)

fit2$pred %>%
  filter(alpha == fit2$bestTune$alpha&
         lambda == fit2$bestTune$alpha) -> best_preds
```

There are two approaches to obtain a metric from these predictions.

Approach 1. you can do it with the combined fold predictions (less frequent but useful when you have small data sets so there is high variance in the fold performance)

```
pROC::roc(best_preds$obs, best_preds$one)$auc
#output
Area under the curve: 0.6631
```

Approach 2. you can calculate it per fold and average (much more common and used by caret  internally for any metric:

```
library(tidyverse)

best_preds %>%
  group_by(Resample) %>%
  summarise(auc = as.numeric(pROC::roc(obs, one)$auc))
#output
  Resample   auc
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 Fold1    0.592
2 Fold2    0.757
3 Fold3    0.614
```

The above is AUC per fold

To average it:

```
best_preds %>%
  group_by(Resample) %>%
  summarise(auc = as.numeric(pROC::roc(obs, one)$auc)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  summarise(mean_auc = mean(auc))
#output
  mean_auc
     <dbl>
1    0.654
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation. It does work and yields the same result as `predict(fit2, df)` does. Could you by any chance also comment as to why there is a difference between the results of two confusion matrices?

Comment: Editing questions with new questions after you receive an answer is discouraged on SO. [When you get a satisfactory answer to a question you should accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If additional questions arise post a new question. In this case I will edit my answer to reflect changes to the question.

Comment: I apologize for not saying this at the beginning, but I posted this question in order to be able to calculate the AUC from the prediction. I realise that there were actually two questions in my original post. 
Nevetherless, you did help me to find the answer. I realised that the product of `dat = fit2$pred` is a data frame, from which I can extract the response that belongs to the best model like this: 
`dat_s = dat[(dat$alpha == 0 & dat$lambda == 0.25),]`
then the correct confusion matrix is simply: 
`table(dat_s$pred, dat_s$obs)`
Thank you for your patience!

Comment: To calculate AUC from the cross validated predictions add the argument  `summaryFunction = twoClassSummary` to `train_control`. This way you will use AUC for model selection. If you plan on using caret [Max Kuhn book](https://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html) is a must read

Comment: I just occurred to me this might be a XY problem. See EDIT2

Comment: It was indeed an XY problem. Thanks for taking your time and giving a well rounded answer.